# How to delete canvas file in reportlab?

Tags: python, canvas, reportlab

My Python program uses reportlab library to generate temporary PDF file for further merging it with existing file:

```
> from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas 
> temp = canvas.Canvas("e:\\temp.pdf")
> ...
> temp.save()
```

The problem I have is I don't know how to delete this temporary file in a correct way. Whenever I try to to do it through os.remove, it restricts access because the file is already busy with my program. Also I fail to find out the correct way to do it via Reportlab methods.

> [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being
>   used by another process:

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Comment: so you could delete that file after your python program exit?

Comment: Yes, of course, I can.  But what is the  most  pythonist way to delete it from my Python program?

Comment: to make sure it is python who holding file handle see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/2937/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-thats-in-use). i checked reportlab source file closed when save, there maybe other culprit.